# How to write iterative version of computing m^n whose time complexity is O(log n)?

Tags: c, algorithm

If I have two integers `m` and `n` , and I have to compute `power(m,n)` i.e. **m<sup>n</sup>** , then I wrote the below recursive code and this gives time complexity as **O(log n)**, but I am unable to write the iterative version of it which gives similar time complexity.

```
int power(int m, int n) {
    int p;
    if (n == 1)
        return m;
    p = power(m, n / 2);
    if (n % 2 == 1) 
        return p * p * m;
    else
        return p * p;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Is there some restriction that prevents you from using the library function [pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/)?

Comment: No , but I wanted to try it with recursive definition

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Maybe because `pow` is floating point? and  bloats the code using floating point library/emulation? There are much more systems without FPU than with in the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the least bit of `n` is `1`, `m` is multiplied to the result.
If the second least bit of `n` is `1`, `m*m` is multiplied to the result.
If the third least bit of `n` is `1`, `(m*m)*(m*m)` is multiplied to the result.

Repeating this, the code should be like this:

```
int power(int m, int n)
{
    int res = 1;
    while (n > 0) /* check all bit which is 1 */
    {
        if (n % 2 == 1) res *= m; /* check current bit */
        m *= m; /* calculate what to multiply if next bit is 1 */
        n >>= 1; /* proceed to next bit */
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain about this m=m*m step , I took an example (3,4) and I am then getting m at the end calculated as 81*81 , so is there any logic behind this ?

Comment: 3^4 = (3^2)^2 = ((3^2)^2)^1 Actually, the result of 81*81 isn't used.

Comment: Note: As youi already use the modulus operator, why not divide `n` instead of shifting?

Comment: It would be more efficient to use `if (n & 1)` instead of `if (n % 2 == 1)` as `n` is signed and the compiler might not detect that `n` is positive.  The code for `n % 2` is longer for the general signed case.

Comment: I like to think that as `a^b = (a*a)^(b/2)`